# Django how to not comment some lines with makemessages

Tags: django, django-commands

#### Problem

I translate my group names in my Django application with the default translation tools.

Since my group names are not hard-coded in my code, when I run `makemessages`, the lines corresponding to my group names are commented out.

#### Example

I have a group named `management_product` which is automatically created during migrations. I put these lines in `django.po`:

```py
msgid "management_product"
msgstr "Gestion des produits"
```

But if I run `django-admin makemessages -l fr`, they are commented out:

```py
#~ msgid "management_product"
#~ msgstr "Gestion des produits"
```

#### Question

How can I disable this behaviour?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Django translations are not meant for dynamic data translations that come from third party data sources like your db. It is meant to translate the static stuff you have in your codebase.

You may want to use something like: https://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ instead.